# Can I fit logistic regression over a dataset with only categorical data?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, fitting

I have a dataset which contains only categorical data i.e.`A,B,C,D` (like factors) for each predictor. There are 10 predictors and the dependent variable is binary, `0,1`.

**UPDATE:** MY predictors are answers for multiple choice questions for a questionnaire. So each predictor only takes on categorical values, i.e. `X_1` can be `A,B,C` or `D`, `X_2` can be `A,B,C,D,E,F,G` or `H`.

**Is it feasible to fit a logistic regression over this dataset?** 
Ideally, if I can fit a logistic regression the data, I will then use it for prediction over a set of test data, which again contains only categorical data.

**What are the pitfalls that I should look out for?**

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. I would watch out for how you're grouping/binning the levels of each predictor to improve credibility and homogeneity. I would also look out for missing data. Lastly, because you're fitting to a logistic regression, you will need to have three separate datasets - one for model fitting, the second to select the logistic probability/value for which you have 0 vs 1 separation, and the third for model validation.

Comment: Yes, you can train a logistic regression model on categorical data. Each feature will be basically on/off which actually simplifies the things. It depends though on implementation how it handles such features.

Comment: Hi @Frank.H, you mentioned that I will need 3 mutually exclusive datasets. I understand the first and third are for training and testing the model. What is the second one for? I thought if the probability computed from the logistic regression is greater than 0.5, then the response variable should be `1`. If `p <0.5`, then response variable should be be `0`. And regarding binning levels of each predictor, since all my predictors have values like `A,B,C` and number of levels for each predictor is different, can I just use`as.factor` for all the predictor variables ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF See: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm

Answer (score 5):

Yes of course you can. Just be aware of the nature of your categorical data - is it ordered or unordered?

If ordered (e.g. small, medium, large) you might want a single feature X1 with values like (1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, ...) where 1 represents small, 2 represents medium, etc.

If unordered (e.g. red, blue, green) you'll want multiple features like X1 = (0, 0, 1, 0) representing "is red?", X2 = (1, 0, 0, 1) representing "is blue?" and so forth.

Comment: Hi, I am not understanding the part where the data is unordered. Can you elaborate on how you create multiple features?

Comment: There's [a lot of discussion about this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20encode%20categorical%20data) if you search for it.  But suppose your training data contains a feature like (red, blue, blue, green, red).  Then you'll want to train your logistic regression model using three features. X1 = IsRed? = (1, 0, 0, 0, 1), X2 = IsBlue? = (0, 1, 1, 0, 0), X3 = IsGreen = (0, 0, 0, 1, 0) where 1s represent "yes" or "true" and 0s represent "no" or "false".  In other words, you create a binary vector for each unique class (i.e. category).

Comment: Upon reading this again, it looks like you're searching for implementation details (i.e. R code) yes?  If so, you should include the `R` tag or possibly consider posting in StackOverflow.

Comment: No, I am not looking for implementation. I just didn't get how you split unordered values into multiple features. That's why I include more details in the quesiton.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is doable.

The (potentially) unseen pitfall is that your model may require a great deal more data than you expect.  A general rule of thumb for logistic regression is that you need at least $15$ observations in the less commonly occurring category (i.e., either $0$s or $1$s) for each variable in the model (cf., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307642/7290)).  You may think that you have just $2$ variables (viz., `X_1` and `X_2`), and thus, you will be OK as long as you have at least $30$ 'successes' and $30$ 'failures'.  However, there is a subtle inconsistency between how we interpret your variables and how a statistical model will use them.  You will quite naturally think of `X_1` as a single variable, but the model will treat it as $3$.  Likewise, the model will treat `X_2` as $7$ (!) additional variables, not one.  More specifically, you are using the number of levels minus one ($4-1=3$ and $8-1=7$) in your model for every categorical variable you add.  The upshot of this is that you want to have at least $150$ 'successes' and $150$ 'failures' ($N>300$) in your dataset to fit a model with just your `X_1` and `X_2` variables.

A related issue is that you want to be sure there are sufficient data in each of those levels.  Obviously, if no one chose `X_2 = G`, you won't be able to estimate anything about the effect of that level of `X_2`, but you will also have a problem if some did choose `G`, but everyone who did has `Y = 1`.  That would lead to the problem of [separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(statistics)).  Moreover, if you want to fit the interaction, you will need sufficient data in every combination of levels ($32$, in your case).  To read more about these topics, you may want to peruse some of our threads categorized under [hauck-donner-effect](/questions/tagged/hauck-donner-effect) and [many-categories](/questions/tagged/many-categories).

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is possible.

You just need to transform your categorical variables into binary variables and to remove each time one item. For instance, if the variable X takes two values A and B, you need to create the variable which is equal to 1 if X == A and to 0 otherwise. Since X == A implies X != B, you'll have a collinearity in your model if you add the variable which is equal to 1 if X == B and to 0 otherwise.

Comment: Hi, if my categorical variable `X` can take values `A,B,C`, do I still need to make them binary ? Can't I just use `as.factor(X)` ?

Comment: You do not need to make your categorical variables to only have two levels. They can have as many as you can justify statistically and meaningfully.

Comment: as.factor(X) is just an R function which makes it easy to transform categorical variables into a set of binary variables.