# Independent variables minimum counts for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, sample-size

I have about 100 samples collected to know the knowledge status of people and it's distributes almost 50 50.
The problem is some of my indipendent variables while making 2x2 the cell value is very less .... All my indipendent variables are binary. Is there any minimum cell count to run Univariable logistic and multivariable logistic?? like for ChiSquare we used to see the expected cell count

Answer (score 1):

"Univariable" logistic regression (which I take to mean using only a single predictor for a binary outcome) is seldom wise if you also have information on other predictors, because of the inherent [omitted-variable bias](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113766/28500) in logistic regression. If you omit any predictor associated with outcome, whether or not it's correlated with the included predictor, your estimate of the coefficient of the included predictor will be biased.

For standard "multivariable" (or "multiple") logistic regression you should generally have on the order of [15 members of the smaller *outcome* class per predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307642/28500) that you are evaluating. If one of your *predictors* is binary and has few cases in one of its classes then the estimate of its coefficient will probably be imprecise, with large standard errors. Depending on the overall structure of the data you might have troubles fitting the model, for example finding [perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28500), but I don't know that there's a general rule for class prevalence within a binary predictor.